# Opengl es strange graphical glitch/behaviour

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

i'm trying to render a simple square on screen, for some reason sometimes it looks ok. and sometimes it doesn't.

[image: here it looks as i wanted]

and here are examples of it looking weird:

[image: not supposed to look like this]

[image: also random weirdness]

[image: another to demonstrate..]

the strange thing is that when i click the recent apps button, the activity's onPause get called, which calls the GlSurfaceView's onPause method..
and when i return to the app it calls onResume as expected.
 and everytime i go out and in again, the graphic looks different..

i've read another question here that seem to be relevant - [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015963/android-opengl-graphical-glitch/)
but according to that, the problem is that when returning to the app, the openGl context was lost and everything needs to be restarted - textures and such.. 
but in my code i do all that in the onSurfaceCreated method, which is called when the app resumes, i also tried to update the Context variable inside the Renderer class, but still no good results.. 
any tips/advice?

Comment: Maybe post your code that issues the draw call. The count you pass to glDrawArrays/glDrawElements should be 4 (for                     GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP) or 6 (for GL_TRIANGLES), but it looks like it's rendering more triangles than that.

Comment: :) you are right... i use GL_TRIANGLES, and passed in the length of the vertex array, only the array contained more information (U.V coordinates etc..) indeed a rookie's mistake